# R shiny hide mainPanel object during computation time

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app with a longer computation depending on the input. I am wondering if it is possible to display a text in the main panel at the same time when the computation is done (and not before).

Let's make an easy example. I simulated the longer computation with `Sys.sleep()`:

```
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

# Application title
   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

# Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30)
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
        h3('This is an example'),
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
))

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- faithful[, 2] 
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
      Sys.sleep(5)
   })
})

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The goal would be, to show the text 'This is an example' at the same time the computation is done and not before.
I think I have to make the text somehow reactive, but so far I haven't found a solution for this. Maybe a `conditionalPanel` could do it, but how can I bring the computation time in the condition? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this be what you search for? Your text variable as a reactive after observing the event of distPlot

```
library(shiny)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      textOutput('text1'),
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
))

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2] 
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    Sys.sleep(2)

  })
  observeEvent(plotOutput("distPlot"), {
    output$text1 <- renderText({ paste("Number of bins:", input$bins)})
  })
  })

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Exactly! Thank you